# Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger

Tags: eclipse, bind, ddms

[86XX error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkhPx.jpg)

This continues to happen. I've followed most of the steps with related issues and I still haven't found a solution to this. Can someone suggest more options to follow in order to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give more information, such as what you were trying to do when the error happened?

Comment: Yes, this error list is generated right after i try to run the application using genymotion galaxy S4. iat first it seems as if was all ok, but then it just pops up that list of errors. and on the emulator it display a message as it just crashed, the application never gets to the emulator

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to kill all processes related to java.

Comment: After uninstalling everything and reinstalling it came to work just fine. thanx